# Count the occurrence of a letter in a list

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp, racket

So far I've tried this, but I'm getting 1:

```
(define occur
  (lambda (a s)
    (count (curry string-contains? a) s)))
```

Ex: `(occur "u" '("u" "uaub" "ubub"))` => 1

It should be 5

Want to avoid using curry since I don't know how it works yet:
[Dr. Racket Recursion count occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936949/dr-racket-recursion-count-occurrences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This drops the reduce for a string-join.

```
(define (how-many items char)
  (define r (regexp (format "[^~a]" char)))
  (string-length (regexp-replace* r (string-join items) "")))

; call it with (how-many '("u" "uaub" "ubub") #\u)
```

But if you don't want to jam all the string together at once, you can sum the individual results.

```
(define (how-many items char)
  (define r (regexp (format "[^~a]" char)))
  (for/sum ((text (in-list items)))
    (string-length (regexp-replace* r text ""))))
```

Comment: what does `"[^~a]"` match?

Comment: The "[^~a\]" is first used by format to generate the string "[^u]" in the case of letter #\u.  A regular expression section with brackets indicates a group of characters and the ^ caret sign means NOT in the context of the bracket, so it finally comes to "any character that is not a 'u'."  Those non-U characters are replaced with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

What is `(string-contains? "abc" "b")` ?

What is `(string-contains? "b" "abc")` ?

Comment: T

      and  F, Since "abc" is not contained within "b"?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of `string-contains?` is:

```
(string-contains? haystack needle)
```

This means *you're currying the wrong argument* when you invoke

```
(curry string-contains? a)
```

This identifies `a` with `haystack`: the string to be searched, not the string to search for. `curry` returns a one-argument function which accepts a `needle` argument, and searches whether it occurs in `a`. Whereas what you want is the other way around.

Fortunately, Racket has solution for you: just add the letter `r` to the `curry` symbol: use the `curryr` function instead, which binds rightmost arguments, and leaves the left free:

```
(curryr string-contains? a)
```

This will make `a` congruent with the `needle` parameter (the thing to find in the larger `haystack`), returning a function which takes the `haystack` argument.

This function is then what you apply to every element of the list, and count the times it returns true.

Illustration of `curry` versus `curryr` over the `cons` function:

```
(map (curry cons 'a) '(1 2 3)) -> ((a . 1) (a . 2) (a . 3))
(map (curryr cons 'd) '(1 2 3)) -> ((1 . d) (2 . d) (3 . d))
```

`(curry cons 'a)` effectively gives us the function `(lambda (arg) (cons 'a arg))`.

`(curryr cons 'd)` effectively gives us the function `(lambda (arg) (cons arg 'd))`.

Partial application and currying can be visualized as a sugar, understandable as a transformation to the explicit and more verbose `lambda` syntax. From time to time that can be helpful if you are confused by some currying situation.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand curry now.

Answer (score 0):

Following loop can also be used to count occurrences. It uses `count` function to find occurrences in list obtained from string:

```
(define (occur c l)
  (let loop ((l l)
             (n 0))
    (cond
      [(empty? l) n]
      [else (loop (rest l)
                  (+ n
                     (count (lambda(x) (equal? x c))
                            (string->list (first l)))))])))
```

Note that "u" is to be sent as character.

Testing:

```
(occur #\u '("u" "uaub" "ubub"))
```

Output:

```
5
```